# How to emit from a redis pubsub listener using flask socketio

Tags: python, flask, redis, publish-subscribe, flask-socketio

I am trying to scale a chatting application which consists of interaction between customer service agent and customer.

If we have multiple instances of backend running, the agent or customer socket can connect(join_room()) to any available instance.

For communication between multiple instances, we added redis pubsub. Whenever we want to emit a message to agent or customer, we will publish the message and room_id to redis channel which will tell all instances to emit the message.

Below is the code which we wrote:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, send
from multiprocessing import Process
import redis

redis_conn = redis.Redis(charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)
pubsub = redis_conn.pubsub()


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = Config.SECRET_KEY
CORS(app)
# Initializing Socket

socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", path="/livechat_backend_sock/socket.io/")



@socketio.on("agent_connect_request")
def agent_connect_request(data):
    print("\n*** agent_connect_request data: ", data)
    msg = {"input_type": "text", "response_type": "live_connecting",
           "response": "Searching for Agent", "data": data}
    if "user_section" in data.keys():
        emit("user_reply", msg)

    # result = some db operations

    # create a room on agent_email_id as it will always be unique
    room_id = result["agent_email_id"]
    msg["agent_details"] = result["agent_data"]

    # some more db operations

    # tell a process to emit on room_id for all instances
    p = Process(target=subs, args=(room_id,))
    p.start()
    join_room(room_id)

    emit("user_reply", msg) # this happens properly
    subscribe_agent(room_id, user_id)

    # publish a message
    pub(data, user_id, room_id, "user_connections")
    # emit("user_connections", data, room=room_id) => this is what is expected after publish

def subscribe_agent(agent_email_id, channel):
    p = Process(target=subs, args=(channel,))
    p.start()


def subs(room):
    pubsub.subscribe(room)
    for message in pubsub.listen():
        if message.get("type") == "message":
            data = json.loads(message.get("data"))
            msg = data.get("message")
            user_id = data.get("from")
            room_id = data.get("to")
            sock = data.get("sock")
            res = subs_emitter(msg, user_id, room_id, sock)


def unsbs(room):
    pubsub.unsubscribe(room)


def pub(msg, user_id, room, sock):
    data = {
        "message": msg,
        "from": user_id,
        "to": room,
        "sock": sock
    }
    redis_conn.publish(user_id, json.dumps(data))


def subs_emitter(msg, user_id, room_id, sock):
    if sock == "user_connections":
        print('on user_connections')
        # code reaches here but emit is not happening
        socketio.emit("user_connections", msg, room=room_id, broadcast=True) 
    if sock == "livechat_agent":
        socketio.emit("livechat_agent", msg, room=room_id)
    if sock == "livechat_user":
        socketio.emit("livechat_user", msg, room=room_id)
    if sock == "agent_group":
        socketio.emit("livechat_user", msg, room=room_id)
    if sock == "liveuser_disconnect_status":
        socketio.emit("liveuser_disconnect_status", msg, room=room_id)
    if sock == "agent_break":
        socketio.emit("agent_break", msg, room=room_id)
    return True
```

When we receive the published message, code is not emitting the message to frontend. Where am I going wrong??

Comment: What is the purpose of implementing all this with Redis when the Socket.lO package already has support for handling multiple server instances? https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-multiple-workers

Comment: As per architecture, the request will always be coming form 1 or 2 ip's and we need to add request from different ip's to the same room, will these rooms work across different instances? Also if we add iphash to nginx, it will point only one or two instance  as we have only one or two ip's.

Comment: The reason you add `ip_hash` to nginx is to support the long-polling transport, which requires that multiple requests by one client always go to the same instance. It has nothing to do with supporting rooms. The multiple worker support in Flask-SocketIO uses redis for coordination across instances, so it is sort of similar to the attempt you are trying to build manually. With this you can emit to a room, and all the participants that joined the room will receive the event, even if they are spread across two or more instances.